# What to say 'one mole of C atoms or one mole of C molecules?

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry, molecules, mole

What to say 'one mole of C atoms or one mole of C molecules in CO? Please point out if I am wrong here
As we know,
one molecule of CO = one mole of CO molecules = 6.223 X 10^23 number of CO molecules
If I split one molecule of CO, we get one C and one O. Here are my questions, What to say these ''one C and one O" one mole of C atoms and one mole of O atoms or ''one mole of C molecules and one mole of O molecules'' or just like above like ''one C and one O''? 
Could you clarify it, please? I am confused

Comment: C molecules is not a thing at all.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to remember when using terminology involving moles is that moles are just a way of counting *things* but that the terminology only makes sense if you unambiguously specify the *thing* you are counting. It is entirely possible to use moles to count non chemical things (for an amusing example of the consequences of having a mole of moles (the small burrowing mammals) see [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/).) Most confusion arises because the way the *thing* is specified is ambiguous.

Some examples:

- a mole of CO molecules is perfectly correct (the units being counted are single molecules of CO)
- A mole of C atoms is perfectly correct (and, if you are counting C atoms in CO molecules that is also fine and the answer will be the same)
- a mole of C *molecules* in CO isn't correct but only because the molecules is CO which consists of *atoms* of C and O.
- if you were counting the atoms in CO2, then it would be correct to say there are twice as many moles of *oxygen atoms* than of carbon atoms or carbon dioxide *molecules*

The use of moles to count doesn't imply anything about what you are counting, you have to specify that as clearly as possible. When talking about the parts of a molecule we usually talk about the *atoms* that make up the molecule. CO2 doesn't consist of *molecules* of oxygen and carbon, but *atoms* of oxygen and carbon. But this is independent of the use of moles as a way of counting those components.

Comment: One non-standard use of mole that I find convenient is that (according to some estimates), the number of stars in the visible universe is about $\frac{1}{10} mole$.  http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/how-many-stars-are-there/